# Tomcat: Attachment errors while using https

Tags: java, tomcat

I've configured tomcat (8.5.16) to use https (using org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol), the application (based on spring framework) works fine (like before, with http) but frequently I have an error when the user upload an attachment. It happens randomly, sometime I have this error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Channel is in closing state
```

and sometimes this:

```
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Stream ended unexpectedly at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:297)
```

Before, using http there were no errors...

Any idea?

Cheers

Matteo

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with http/2, not https.
Removing this

```
    <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
```

from connector, it works as well as before.

Matteo